# 'Option Strict' set to 'Off'

Tags: vb.net

I have read Jeff Atwood's blog post, *[Option Strict and Option Explicit in VB.NET 2005](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/option-strict-and-option-explicit-in-vbnet-2005.html)*.

I am interested in the statement: "You should ALWAYS turn Option Strict On for every application".

I agree that in an object-oriented programming language, that this should be set to ON. However, every application I look at seems to have it set to OFF.  Also most of the code fragments I find online seem to suggest that the developer has switched this off e.g. I see this a lot:

```
dim id as Integer = objDR("ID")
```

Here the object is implicitly casted into an integer.

Is there a specific criteria that developers use when deciding to switch this off or is it just to be consistent with [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an appropriate question for SO. You're basically asking us to defend someone else's decision that just might be plain bad. ("code fragments I find online" is a great indicator that this is the case, really. Code on DevShed or CodeProject tends to be just sad.)

Comment: Depends on your coding style. Yes, the reason it's off by default is to keep consistent with VB6.

Comment: Generally speaking, the more error checking you let the compiler do the less debugging you will have to do.  Having it turned off is ok for rapid prototyping when you're playing with programming ideas and you don't want the extra warnings and error associated with strict typing to break a train of thought.  But all this is highly subjective.  Other schools of thought say break bad habits before they start.  Can't really argue with that.  In the end it's personal preference.

Comment: @fnostro, thanks.  Is it fair to say that a lot of production apps have this switched off?

Comment: @w0051977 Seriously now, that's just impossible for any single person to tell, definitely not objectively. The best you can get is a poll of a few people going "from the VB.NET production apps I've worked on, X had it off", and whatever information you get will be inconclusive because the sample size for the number of projects, and the number of companies (which would likely have guidelines / habits that would make this choice consistent across projects) would be tiny.

Comment: @w0051977 As millimoose stated - there is no way to know that. the only thing that's fair to say is that VB, whatever version you talking about, has defaults and they try to maintain backward compatibility.  Personally, If I'm dealing with legacy code, I leave settings alone.

Comment: For me the happy medium is to set it On but change the compiler to produce warnings instead of errors.

Comment: Additionally having the habit of keeping it on, makes your code look more well thought out, instead of just slapped together.

Comment: @dbasnett, thanks.  Your comment answers my question.  Can you post an answer, maybe?

Comment: Oh I feel strongly about this: If `Option Strict On` is not set in your options, your code is bad. Full stop. Microsoft did us a **huge** disservice by not making `On` the default. I’m furious at them for still not having rectified this. Backwards compatibility is *no* good justification for the evil this inflicts.

Comment: @w0051977 - per your request posted as answer.

Comment: @Konrad - they didn't.  Use Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VB Defaults to set your preference.  Feel free to get furious about you not looking what's there ;)

Comment: @Hans Good to know. I ditched Windows ages ago. Last I used .NET it was not the default. But then I’m at a loss why we still get x beginners a week on Stack Overflow whose code uses `Option Strict Off`, and who clearly have never heard of this option.

Answer (score 2):

In VB6, it is often impossible to determine at compile time to determine the type of certain variables, fields, or parameters.  Some such storage locations will in practice always hold items of one particular type; some, however, may hold different things at different times.  Suppose unrelated types `Moe` and `Larry` both have a property named `Curly`, and a method which takes a parameter `Foo` of unspecified type says `Foo.Curly = 5`.  If such a method could be passed either a `Moe` or a `Larry`, cleanly porting the code to the `Option Strict On` dialect of VB.NET would require either it be written as two distinct overloads: one that takes a `Moe`, and one that takes a `Larry`, or that `Moe` and `Larry` be modified to implement a common interface with a member `Curly`.  In cases where either those approaches would be workable, code should ported to the `Option Strict On` dialect of VB.NET.  Some existing VB6 code, however, would not be amenable to either fix; porting such code to the `Option Strict Off` dialect may be much easier than reworking it to work with `Option Strict On`.

In some cases, I would consider the use of `Option Strict Off` justifiable when trying to port existing VB6 code which cannot be wrangled to be compatible with `Option Strict On`.  I see no reason, however, to create any new design which would require any substantial use of that dialect.  Many of the behaviors associated with it do not interact well with newer features of .NET such as generics, relational operators do not yield consistent results (e.g. "-1" is greater than -2 and -2 is greater than "-3", but "-1" is less than "-3"), and it's often hard to predict what a given piece of code will end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [answer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/33xw7fts%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Specifying data types for all your programming elements is known as strong typing. When you set Option Strict On, Visual Basic enforces strong typing. This is strongly recommended, for the following reasons:
>
> It enables IntelliSense support for your variables and parameters. This allows you to see their properties and other members as you type in your code.
>
> It allows the compiler to perform type checking. This helps catch statements that can fail at run time due to errors such as overflow. It also catches calls to methods on objects that do not support them.
>
> It results in faster execution of your code. One reason for this is that if you do not specify a data type for a programming element, the Visual Basic compiler assigns it the Object type. Your compiled code might have to convert back and forth between Object and other data types, which reduces performance.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zcd4xwzs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#conditions)

> To set warning configurations in the IDE
>
> When you use the Compile Page, Project Designer (Visual Basic) instead
>   of an Option Strict statement, you have additional control over the
>   conditions that generate errors. The Warning configurations section of
>   the Compile Page has settings that correspond to the three conditions
>   that cause a compile-time error when Option Strict is on. Following
>   are these settings:
>
> ```
> Implicit conversion
>
> Late binding; call could fail at run time
>
> Implicit type; object assumed
> ```
>
> When you set Option Strict to On, all three of these warning
>   configuration settings are set to Error. When you set Option Strict to
>   Off, all three settings are set to None.
>
> You can individually change each warning configuration setting to
>   None, Warning, or Error. If all three warning configuration settings
>   are set to Error, On appears in the Option strict box. If all three
>   are set to None, Off appears in this box. For any other combination of
>   these settings, (custom) appears.